# Search a text in a SQL Server 2012 database

Tags: sql-server-2012

I have 10+ databases on my server each one with stored procedures, views, etc. I want to delete one database but I need to track that database on the others to see if is used on another database.

Is there any way to do this or I need to look manually?

Comment: Why don't you query the database for what you're looking for?  Please provide more details in your question.

Comment: provide some details, an example would be best

Comment: i'm going to delete PromoNet_Historic, but in the same server i have anothers DB's like PromoNEt, SIP, WorkDB, etc.
 I need to know where is used PromoNet_Historic in the others DB's, is there any comand line to know that or something

Comment: The content of your question seems unrelated to the title?  Please clarify.

Answer (score 0):

You could do that checking:

1. If a login is using the database.
2. Are reads and writes happening in PromoNet_Historic database.
3. Is the Transaction Counter Going Up for the Database?
4. Are the user executions plans in the cache for the database?

Check this link for the query command lines -> [4 Lightweight Ways To Tell If a Database is being used](http://www.brentozar.com/archive/2014/05/4-lightweight-ways-tell-database-used/)